# Cocoapods warnings, dyld warnings

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm running `pod update` on file with 2 dependencies (crittercism and protobufs)

Then I get output like this:

```
Analyzing dependencies
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../../../../../../../SharedFrameworks in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../..//DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTInstrumentsFoundation being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/Xcode3Core being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
Downloading dependencies
Installing CrittercismSDK (5.4.11)
Installing GoogleProtobuf (2.6.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Sending stats

[!] Unable to read the license file `/Users//Documents/DMD/Pods/GoogleProtobuf/COPYING.txt` for the spec `GoogleProtobuf (2.6.1)`

[!] Unable to read the license file `/Users//Documents/DMD/Pods/GoogleProtobuf/COPYING.txt` for the spec `GoogleProtobuf (2.6.1)`
```

What do those warnings mean? And also, what is this about "Unable to read license file?" Is that just a problem with specific pod build or should I do something about it? It's latest Protobufs